# How to fix: My second if statement gets a syntax error and I don't know why?

Tags: python, pylint

The problem is that python tells me that the syntax for the second if statement is done wrong and I have no clue why...
Don't mind that some of the code is in Danish.

I have tried to redo the entire code but with the same result...

```
import math

x = float(input("Indtast 1 for trekant eller 2 for cirkel: "))

if (x == 1):
    a = float(input("Indtast side a: "))
    b = float(input("Indtast side b: "))
    c = float(input("Indtast side c: "))

    s = (1/2) * (a + b + c)
    areal = math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))

    print("")
    print("Arealet er " + str(areal)

if (x == 2):
    pi = 3.14
    radius = float(input("indtast radius "))
    omkreds = radius * 2 * pi
    areal = radius * radius * pi

    print("")
    print("Det er arealet", areal)
    print("")
    print("Det er omkredsen", omkreds)

else:
    print("")
    print("KÆMPE FAIL! KA' DU IK' LÆSE!")
```

I expected that the code would run without any failures but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is missing a closing parentheses:

```
print("Arealet er " + str(areal)
```

Comment: Omg you're right... I can't believe that i overlooked that. Amazing. Thank you so much!